# Извлечение именованных сущностей : сеть или словари?

Tags: нейронные-сети, словари, nlp

**Дано**: большой набор excel-файлов(тысячи, десятки тысяч).

**Задача**: извлечь из файлов названия различных географических объектов, организаций, а также специальных терминов предметной области.

Если приложить достаточные усилия, то можно сформировать словари с нужными ключевыми словами (примерно до 10 тысяч).

**Варианты**:
1. На основе словарей извлекать и классифицировать сущности
2. На словарях обучить нейронную сеть и использовать её

Первый вариант проще, но второй тоже не зря ж придуман и используется. Какой же предпочтительнее? На что опираться при выборе варианта?

Comment: Название бы полей не помешало.

Comment: @edem не поняла Вашу мысль

Comment: Названия полей (стоблцов) из excel-записей добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Нет единого формата файлов, как и названий полей. Разные документы разного формата. заранее мы не знаем поля.